# Makefile fails to build kernel module "recipe commences before first target"

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I tried to build example 2.1 from https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/lkmpg.pdf.

I tried googling for answers and all related threads came down on the Makefile being copied over wrong. So i tried retyping the makefile and i also tried other peoples Makefile. But i keep getting the same errors.

lkm.c:

```c
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += lkm.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

This is the error i get:

```
philip@ubuntu:~/test$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.0.0-20-generic/build M=/home/philip/test modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-20-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/philip/test/lkm.c', needed by '/home/philip/test/lkm.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1605: _module_/home/philip/test] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-20-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Not sure if it matters to you, but your name may be visible in that stack you posted.

Comment: no problemo. i'm aware.

Comment: Did you install kernel headers?

Comment: linux-headers-5.0.0-20-generic is installed

Comment: Put `make V=1` instead of `make` in the target *all:* in above *Makefile* and provide an output.

Comment: Well, the error message is clear: you don't have `lkm.c` file under `/home/philip/test` directory. May be, you have this file somewhere else, or name this file in another way. You may try to run `ls /home/philip/test/lkm.c` for check the file existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The file in my directory was called lkm instead of lkm.c. Thanks for the replies :)